# how to parse html already store in variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to parse a shoutcast page like this :
http://relay.181.fm:8800/played.html
So, i just make ajax to call a php file. The php file return all the content of the page.
i store the html content to a var in js. Here is the code: 
PHP:

```
function getcontent($server, $port, $file){
    $cont = "";
    $ip = gethostbyname($server);
    $fp = fsockopen($ip, $port);
    if (!$fp){
        return "Unknown";
    }
    else{
        $com = "GET $file HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: */*\r\nAccept-Language: de-ch\r\n"
        ."Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;"
        ." MSIE 6.0;Windows NT 5.0)\r\nHost: $server:$port\r\n"
        ."Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n";
        fputs($fp, $com);
        while (!feof($fp))
        {
            $cont .= fread($fp, 500);
        }
        fclose($fp);
        $cont = substr($cont, strpos($cont, "\r\n\r\n") + 4);
        return $cont;
        }
}
echo (getcontent("relay.181.fm", "8800", "/played.html"));
```

Here is my js:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var parsed;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        parsed=xhr.response;

    }
};
xhr.open("GET", 'http://localhost/getsong.php', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

And that is what i want to get:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var songs=new Array();
var time=new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    songs[i]=$('table:eq(2) tr:eq('+(i+1)+') td:eq(1)').text();
    time[i]=$('table:eq(2) tr:eq('+(i+1)+') td:eq(0)').text();
};
});
```

if i copy the xhr.response content and i put it in the html file and i execute this js, it return me exactly what i want.
but i dont get how i can do when the html is in a variable... :'(

PS: i work on a wamp env., And a node.js env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged it with jQuery, why not use the built in ajax functionality:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'http://localhost/getsong.php',
     dataType: 'html'
 }).done(function(data){
      //do something with the HTML
      var $html = $(data),
          tdtexts = $html.find('table:eq(2) tr td:first').text();
 });
```

Is this what you're asking for?

Comment: Yeah, Totally, Thanks !!!
i cant tumbs up.. but i will when i will get more reputation!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use innerHTML to resolve

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var parsed;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        parsed=xhr.response;  
        document.getElementById('#div').innerHTML =  parsed;

    }
};
xhr.open("GET", 'http://localhost/getsong.php', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: The johan solution is really better.
no need to hide this in a page.
but thank's.

Answer (score 0):

Proceeding further after getting `response` may help you like,

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var parsed;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        parsed=$.parseHTML(xhr.response);
        var songs=new Array();
        var time=new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            songs[i]=$(parsed).find('table:eq(2) tr:eq('+(i+1)+') td:eq(1)').text();// use find function for parsed string
            time[i]=$(parsed).find('table:eq(2) tr:eq('+(i+1)+') td:eq(0)').text();
        };
    }
};
xhr.open("GET", 'http://localhost/getsong.php', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

By using [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost/getsong.php',
        dataType:'html',
        success:function(parsed){
            var songs=new Array();
            var time=new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                songs[i]=$(parsed).find('table:eq(2) tr:eq('+(i+1)+') td:eq(1)').text();// use find function for parsed string
                time[i]=$(parsed).find('table:eq(2) tr:eq('+(i+1)+') td:eq(0)').text();
            };
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for jQuery.parseHTML(). It will parse your string into an array of DOM nodes.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/

Here's a quick example for your case:

```
$.get('http://relay.181.fm:8800/played.html')
.done(function(data) {
    var parsed = $.parseHTML(data);
    // Now parsed is an array of DOM elements which you can use selectors on, eg:
    var song1 = $(parsed).find('table:eq(2) tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)').text();
    console.log(song1);
});
```